# Static methods in Kotlin as static method in Java

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a static method in Kotlin, that allows proper inter-op with Java.

Context: I want to pass a `java.lang.reflect.Method` reference to `org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext#registerFunction` so add custom functionality to Spring's expression Language.

I created a companion object:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun foo(): Boolean = true
}
```

And get the reference via

```
Companion::foo.javaMethod!!
```

or

```
Companion.javaClass.getMethod("foo").modifiers
```

However, when I call `Modifier.isStatic` on the result, it returns `false` and when I try to evaluate an expression with the registered function, I also get

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
EL1039E: Only static methods can be called via function references.
The method '…$Companion.foo' referred to by name 'foo' is not static.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: with `@JvmStatic` you make the method static in the containing class, not in the companion object. Use the enclosing class as a reference.

Comment: `ContainingClass::foo` doesn't work and when I try `Modifier.isStatic(ContainingClass.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("foo").modifiers)` its also `false`

Comment: It does work when I use a package-level method

Comment: Nonetheless I'd be curious to find out why the other approach is not working

Comment: What IDE are you using? I tried it and `ContainingClass.javaClass` has a warning because it returns `Class<ContainingClass.Companion>` which is obviously not what you want.  You're supposed to use `ContainingClass::class.java` and it will work.

Comment: IntelliJ; you are right, I didn't notice the warning when I tried the explicit reflection API as I concentrated on the kotlin literal access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me this way:

```
class C {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun foo(): Boolean = true
    }
}

val method = C::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("foo")

Modifier.isStatic(method.modifiers) // true
```

Note that `C::class.java` and `C.javaClass` are different things: the former returns `Class<C>` and the latter returns `Class<C.Companion>`.

Comment: Good catch, this does work!
Downside is that the `::` operator is not working for this, whereas it does work with package-level methods. So I can use `::foo.javaMethod`, `Companion::foo.javaMethod` (gives the non-static function), but I cannot say `ContainingClass::foo`.